# Estimate the square root of the success probability of a Binomial Distribution.

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, binomial-distribution, parameter-estimation

Let $B(n,p)$ be a Binomial Distribution. Consider the following estimate of $p$ :

\begin{equation}
\hat{p} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N X_i}{nN}
\end{equation}
where $X_i \sim B(n,p)$ are independent samples.
We have \begin{equation}
\mathrm{Var}[\hat{p}] = \frac{p(1-p)}{n N}
\end{equation}
It is not hard to see that this estimate for $p$ has optimal rate of convergence.

**Question**

Consider now the situation where we need to approximate $q = \sqrt{p}$ given samples from $B(n,p)$. Is it possible to get an estimate $\hat{q}$ that achieves $\mathrm{Var}[\hat{q}] = q (1-q)/(n N) $? Is there a better solution than to simply take $\hat{q} = \sqrt{\hat{p}}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The Wald 95% confidence interval for $p$ is of the form
$$\hat p \pm 1.96\sqrt{\hat p(1-\hat p)/n},$$
where $\hat p = X/n,$ the proportion of Successes in $n$ trials.

To get a 95% CI for $q = \sqrt{p}$ take the square root of the
endpoints of the CI for $p.$

Especially for small $n$ or for $p$ near to $0$ or $1$ a the more accurate Argesti 95% CI for $p$ is of the form

$$\check p \pm 1.96\sqrt{\check p(1-\check p)/\check n},$$
where $\check n = n+2$ and $\check p = (X + 2)/\check n.$  By 'more accurate' I mean that the true probability
of covering $p$ is closer to the claimed 95% than for the Wald interval.
So you could get a more accurate 95% CI for $q$ by taking square roots
of the endpoints of the Argreti interval.

*Note:* The same idea is used to get a confidence interval for the population
standard deviation $\sigma$ from a confidence interval for the population
variance $\sigma^2.$

Comment: I would like to draw $O(1/poly(\epsilon))$ samples and get an estimate $\hat{q}$ of $\sqrt{p}$ such that $|\hat{q} - \sqrt{p}| \leq \epsilon \sqrt{\frac{ \sqrt{p} (1-\sqrt{p})}{n}}$. I don't think that Argesti's estimate will be asymptotically better than $\sqrt{\hat{p}}$.

Comment: Perhaps if you would put your ideas and motivation _into your Question,_ someone might be more helpful.